# Access VBA - Iterate through report elements/properties

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am looking for a way to iterate all the report elements and properties in an Access VBA. My main objective is to check to see if elements (likely text boxes and/or labels) contain a certain string, and then replace that string, output the report, etc. I know how to check and replace the string and output the report, but I cannot find a way to iterate through individual report elements to check their properties. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Updated answer to include Label Caption and Textbox Value prioperties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access - the elements you refer to are called controls.

You can loop through all controls of a report - if you want to change their captions (for labels) or values (unbound textboxes) - you can use the loop to conditionally check for the string in the property based on the control type

**Something like this would likely work for you:**

> Edit - change rpt variable to AccessObject

```
Public Sub ChangeReportStrings(oldString as String, newString as String)
   Dim rpt as AccessObject
   Dim ctl as Control

   For Each rpt in currentProject.AllReports
       DoCmd.OpenReport rpt.Name, acViewDesign 
       For Each ctl in rpt.Controls
           Select Case ctl.ControlType
               Case acLabel
                   ' Replace Label Caption old string with new string
                    ctl.Caption = Replace(ctl.Caption, oldString , newString)
               Case acTextBox
                   ' Probably should check to see if ControlSource is filled first
                   ' Replace ctl.Value old String with new String
                   ctl.Value = Replace(ctl.Value, oldString , newString)

           End Select
       Next ctl
       DoCmd.Close acReport, rpt.Name, acSaveYes
   Next rpt

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. For the "each rpt in currentproject.allreports", it's throwing me a type mismatch error. I have rpt declared as Report as you do. Any advice?

Comment: Hmmm - good pickup. It looks like it' should be an AccessObject. Change the declaration to AccessObject as in `Dim rpt as AccessObject` (as per docs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194322.aspx) I modified my answer - see if that works now

Comment: I got it working. I had to iterate using AccessObject, but then to change the controls, I needed to toss it into a Report object.

Comment: Nice - thanks for updating. Let me know if above code should be modified by setting report to access object